# Es posible devolver una consulta eloquent excluyendo los primero x registros?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo una consulta y necesito retornar todos los registros exceptuando el rango de 1-20 registros dependiendo de lo que existan, ejemplo podría tener en una consulta 35, 50 o más, pero también 15, 10, menos de veinte... Lo que requiero es que si hay entre 1-20 registros se obvien y en caso de haber más de 20 enviarlos pero desde el número veinte, excluyendo los anteriores.

```
$photos = Photo::where('year', '=', $year)->take(20)->get(); // Sé que puedo tomar los primeros 20 registros, pero como puedo excluir los primeros 20?
```

Comment: A que no los agregue a la colección

Comment: Ejemplo: si hago una consulta y hay 35 registros, enviar desde el el número 20 hasta 35, pero en caso que haya menos de 20 no regrese nada.

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con skip(20) pero no he probado sin poner el take(), ya que estaría actuando como un limit(20, x) al rato hago pruebas y te aviso, solo te quería dar la idea de con que podrías resolverlo por el momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar [skip / take](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries):

> Para limitar el número de resultados devueltos de la consulta, o para omitir un número determinado de resultados en la consulta, puede utilizar los métodos de omitir y tomar:

Ejemplo:

```
$photos = Photo::where('year', '=', $year)->skip(20)->take(20)->get();
```

Y si quieres recibir todos los registros después de los 20 puedes usar la constante [PHP_INT_MAX](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.constants.php)

Ejemplo:

```
$photos = Photo::where('year', '=', $year)->skip(20)->take(PHP_INT_MAX)->get();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lovoy a intentar así también

Answer (score 1):

- Primero realiza un conteo del modelo de esta forma:

  ```
  $conteo = Photo::count();
  ```

Lo anterior nos devolverá un número indicando la cantidad de registros en la tabla asociada a dicho modelo.

Ahora establecemos un condicional donde:

- Primero verificamos si el conteo devolvió un valor menor a 20 para indicar alguna acción en concencuencia
- Si la condición anterior no se cumple entonces hacemos la consulta y hacemos uso de un método `where` para establecer que la consulta se maneje sobre aquellos registros cuyo `id` sea mayor o igual a 20

Consulta:

```
$conteo = Photo::count();

if($conteo <= 20) 
{
    return "Nada que mostrar";
} else {
    $consulta = Photo::where('id', '>=', 20)->get();
    return $consulta;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!,

Comment: Ya lo intento y te aviso

Comment: Me está dando un error, lo reviso mañana y te comento

Comment: Gracias, funcionó... No se me ocurrió hacerlo con el id, la hora :) muchas gracias!